# Python Dictionary - How to find all keys with the lowest amount of unique value?

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary:

```
dict = {'a' : [1, 2], 'b' : [1], 'c' : [3, 3, 3]}
```

How do I find which keys have the lowest amount of unique values? In this case, it would be the dictionary with the keys 'b' and 'c' as they each only have 1 unique value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
d = {'a' : [1, 2], 'b' : [1], 'c' : [3, 3, 3]} #avoid using 'dict' as name of dictionary

temp={k:len(set(v)) for k, v in d.items()} #get the count of unique values for each key

res=[i for i in temp if temp[i]==min(temp.values())] #get the keys with min value

>>> print(res)
['b', 'c']
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! It has helped me with my project tremendously!

Comment: Happy to help :) Don't forget to upvote proper answers, now that you passed 15 rep. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can create an inverted mapping using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and access the keys corresponding to the least number of unique values:

```
from collections import defaultdict 

d = {'a' : [1, 2], 'b' : [1], 'c' : [3, 3, 3]}

# dictionary mapping len of unique values to corresponding key
d2 = defaultdict(list)
for k in d:
    d2[len(set(d[k]))].append(k)
```

```
print (d2)
# defaultdict(list, {2: ['a'], 1: ['b', 'c']})

print (d2[min(d2)])
# ['b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
d = {'a' : [1, 2], 'b' : [1], 'c' : [3, 3, 3]}

ml={i:len(set(m)) for i,m in d.items()}

res={i:d[i] for i,z in ml.items() if z==min(ml.values())}

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the following three steps

```
# Create a dictionary d with format {key: number of unique values}
d = {key: len(set(value)) for key, value in dict.items()}

# Find the minimum value in this dictionary
min_value = min(d.values())

# Find all the keys with value equal to the minimum
min_list = [key for key, value in d.items() if value == min_value]
```

The result will be a list containing b and c in your example

Answer (score 0):

You could use an auxiliary dict or comprehension as in other answers if you need to do further processing, otherwise IMO no need for anything fancy, a simple for loop should do the trick, using `set()` conversion as a quick way to count unique values

As a minor aside, it's recommended not to use `dict` as your dict variable name since it's a reserved keyword in python and it will shadow use of that keyword

```py
def keys_with_fewest_uniq_values(d):
    min_num_uniq, min_keys = None, []
    for key, val in dict.items():
        num_uniq = len(set(val))
        if min_num_uniq is None or num_uniq < min_num_uniq:
            min_num_uniq = num_uniq
            min_keys = [key]
        elif num_uniq == min_num_uniq:
            min_keys.append(key)
    return min_keys

>> my_dict = {'a' : [1, 2], 'b' : [1], 'c' : [3, 3, 3]}
>> print(keys_with_fewest_uniq_values(my_dict))        
['b','c']
```